# Splitting a variable into two new variables in R

Tags: r, split

So I'm using the data-set bcmort from the ISwR package in R studio. The data set contains information about breast cancer deaths in Denmark and other areas before screening was introduced.

What I want to do is take the cohort variable (which consists of 4 levels) and split it into the variables 'Period' and 'Area'.

Any idea how I would go about doing this?

Thanks in advance

Edit:
I think it might help if showed the levels of cohort:
[image]

The four levels are: Study Group, National study group, Historical Study Group, Historical National Study Group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not knowing what your desired output looks like, here is a generic solution using fuctions from `dplyr` and `stringr`. I can guess from those four factor levels how you might like to construct your new variables `Area` and `Period`, but I don't know if my approach is what you want.

From my quick examination, I would guess that your `Area` variable is based on whether the `Cohort` was "national" or not. I would guess that the `Period` variable is based on whether the `Cohort` was "historical" or not. In this case, I will use `str_detect` from the `stringr` package to detect patterns in the cohort value. I will use `mutate` to create the new columns.

```
library(ISwR)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

bcmort %>%
  mutate(Period = if_else(str_detect(cohort, "Hist"), "Historical", "Not historical")) %>%
  mutate(Area = if_else(str_detect(cohort, "Nat|nat"), "National", "Not national"))

     age        cohort bc.deaths    p.yr         Period         Area
1  50-54     Study gr.         9   64144 Not historical Not national
2  55-59     Study gr.        34   92734 Not historical Not national
3  60-64     Study gr.        43   83510 Not historical Not national
4  65-69     Study gr.        53   87408 Not historical Not national
5  70-74     Study gr.        56   77427 Not historical Not national
6  75-79     Study gr.        28   25600 Not historical Not national
7  50-54      Nat.ctr.        89  767111 Not historical     National
8  55-59      Nat.ctr.       434 1067778 Not historical     National
9  60-64      Nat.ctr.       516  906943 Not historical     National
10 65-69      Nat.ctr.       535  826254 Not historical     National
11 70-74      Nat.ctr.       545  635385 Not historical     National
12 75-79      Nat.ctr.       214  192946 Not historical     National
13 50-54     Hist.ctr.        22   57669     Historical Not national
14 55-59     Hist.ctr.        45  113143     Historical Not national
15 60-64     Hist.ctr.        82  139065     Historical Not national
16 65-69     Hist.ctr.       104  155697     Historical Not national
17 70-74     Hist.ctr.       128  128454     Historical Not national
18 75-79     Hist.ctr.        57   40196     Historical Not national
19 50-54 Hist.nat.ctr.       104  577528     Historical     National
20 55-59 Hist.nat.ctr.       443  931245     Historical     National
21 60-64 Hist.nat.ctr.       485  916923     Historical     National
22 65-69 Hist.nat.ctr.       491  838476     Historical     National
23 70-74 Hist.nat.ctr.       418  608008     Historical     National
24 75-79 Hist.nat.ctr.       182  182824     Historical     National
```

If I have guessed incorrectly, then you can adapt to what your desired output looks like.

Comment: Yeah sorry, i wasn't sure how to word my problem, however, this is perfect. Thanks a lot